# Elasticsearch search_analyzer at query time

Tags: elasticsearch

Can we provide a search_analyzer like whitespace at query time? 
Something like this :

```
"multi_match": {
  "query": "423.0",
  "type": "phrase",
  "search_analyzer": "whitespace",
  "fields": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the field name is `analyzer`.

Example:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "quick brown f",
      "type":       "phrase_prefix",
      "analyzer":   "whitespace",
      "fields":     [ "subject", "message" ]
    }
  }
}
```

For more details please take a look into the documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html